# Explicit call pseudo destructor in clang

Tags: c++, clang

I'm trying to call explicit pseudo destructor:

```cpp
namespace ns {
    template<typename D>
    struct bar {};
}

template <typename T>
void example(T x)
{
    ns::bar<T>().~NoWay<T>();
}
```

Clang++ (version 3.3) compiles this code without any errors. But `NoWay` not defined in the code. Is this right behavior?

Comment: Have you tried compiling a call to example? Until you force it to be instantiated various errors may not be detected.

Comment: have you tried actually calling your example function? The compiler will only create the function if it's being called somewhere

Comment: No. I'm only interested why it's successfully compiled. Should it be parsed or complains about error? From standard point of view.

Comment: @dyp Name lookup of NoWay is required because it isn't a member of the current instantiation. It's a member of an unknown instantiation, and it's not qualified by `template`. (Although, it's not clear that the syntax exists to use `template` here without a nested-name-specifier.) I think the failure should occur immediately.

Comment: I know I said I'd sleep now, but… there's no "currently" constraint in the requirement that a valid specialization exist. The standard is a bit ambiguous about the sample space of potential template arguments, but it makes sense only if broadened to all types in the whole program, or innocuous, extraneous headers would quickly go awry. An interpretation encompassing all types and values that could ever potentially exist makes even more sense.

Comment: @dyp Not optional. Actually GCC's complaint is the angle braces (as relational operators), and I'm surprised that Clang found a template-name there.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Ok, looked it up, agree with you now :) Why do you say that "it's not clear that the syntax exists"? Is there something that contradicts/extends [expr.post]/1?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Potatoswatter now :) The program is ill-formed:

[temp.names]/4

> When the name of a member template specialization appears after `.` or `->` in a *postfix-expression* or [...], and the object expression of the *postfix-expression* is type-dependent
>   or [..], the member template name must be prefixed by the keyword `template`.
>   Otherwise the name is assumed to name a non-template.

A non-template would mean the `<` in `NoWay<T>` would be parsed as a less-than, which makes no sense being followed by a *typedef-name* (and the `~` would also be illegal, potentially naming but not calling a destructor).

One would think that adding a `template` here:

```
ns::bar<T>().template ~NoWay<T>();
```

would make it well-formed. The part `template ~NoWay<T>` can indeed be a valid *pseudo-destructor-name*, [expr.post]/1

> *pseudo-destructor-name:*
>      *nested-name-specifier<sub>opt</sub> type-name* `:: ~` *type-name*
>      *nested-name-specifier* `template` *simple-template-id* `:: ~` *type-name*
>      *nested-name-specifier<sub>opt</sub>* `~` *type-name*

but only if there's a *nested-name-specifier* before the `template` (note: it's not optional!).